# DDOS Safety Electrum?

Tags: electrum, attack

How hard would it be to successfully attack (all) the Electrum backend servers? I think there is about a handful of them.

I would consider an attack successful that stops Electrum from working for a day or so.

Comment: Please note: my knowledge about Electrum is quite limited but I think it is possible to export your keys without access to the servers so that you can access your coins via some other client even if the servers are not accessible.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're asking; nevertheless the wiki says:

> Transactions are signed locally: Your private keys are not shared with the server. You do not have to trust the server with your money.
>
> Freedom and Privacy: The server does not store user accounts. You are not tied to a particular server, and the server does not need to know you.

It seems the storage of your keys is client-side, so if they were to get (D)DoS'd you could easily move you keys to another wallet.

Comment: Still a medium sized botnet could easily ddos all available servers? and while they're at it the blockchain.info server, too.